# Facebook. Post to own facebook page as page

Tags: facebook, post

I want automatically post to my own facebook page as page not user after user creates article on my website.

First of all: it is possible to do that without user authorization?

I already tried:

```
FB.api(
            "/page_id/feed",
            "POST",
            {
                'access_token': pageAccessToken,
                "message": "This is a test message"
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
```

But got error that user not authorized.. Maybe there is way to work around and automatically post to my own facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this message

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

That would mean you didn't grant `publish_actions` permissions for the session user.

You need user authorisation at some point in the process then you extend the user token. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal#extend_token

Once you have an extended token get the page token, and that token will have no expiry.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

> A page access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page.

Comment: So, without user authentication is not possible to post, yes?

Comment: @BeG yes, user auth needs to be done at least once. After that you can rely on the page token.

Comment: Now I have extended page token, but there are new problem. Then all posts goes to facebook page with my name and I want to post as page. It is possible?

Comment: @BeG that shouldn't be possible if you're posting with a page token and not a user token.

Comment: But why with short-lived access token I can post as page and with  long-lived can't? I don't get it..

Comment: @BeG you either are encountering a bug or doing something wrong.

Comment: I got extended page token from this tutorial: http://luisramalho.com/how-to-get-the-facebook-access-token-the-extended-page-access-token-that-never-expires/
Maybe could you see and say it's good or bad one?

Comment: @BeG the tutorial is missing a last step. Grab the page token from the `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[EXTENDED_ACCESS_TOKEN]` response. In that response will list all the pages you admin and a list of tokens that come with them. You can also do this instead `https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]?fields=access_token&access_token=[EXTENDED_ACCESS_TOKEN]` Where `[page_id]` is the page you want to post to.